# How can I access latitude and longitude after calculating distance and checking whis one closer?

Tags: c#, distance, latitude-longitude, minimum

I have a list of points, called intersect. This list is order like this:

```
latitudePoint1,longitudePoint1,latitudePoint2,longitudePoint2,latitudePoint3,longitudePoint3,...
```

So that the latitude and longitude of the same point have different indexes.
I calculate the distance of those points to an fixed point and then I need to check which one of those points is closest to the fixed point(hardcoded).
I try to explain everything better with comments bellow:

```
 List<double> distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao = new List<double>();

 for (int i = 0; i <= intersect.Count(); i++)
            {
                 //get latitude
                double intLat = intersect[2 * i];
                //get longitude
                double intLong = intersect[2 * i + 1];
                //calculates the distance between the fixed point and the point of the list intersect
                var distancia = GetDistance(FixedLatitude, FixedLongitude, intLat.ToString(), 
                intLong.ToString());

                //Add the latitude and longitude and long as the distance calulated to another list 
                distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.Add(intLat);
                distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.Add(intLong);
                distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.Add(distancia);

                
            }
```

Now I need to check which one of the distances added to the list distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao is the closer to the fixed point and then return the latitude and longitude associated with that distance.

Here is what I've done so far:

```cs
for (int j = 0; j <= distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.Count(); j++) 
{
    // I need to at least have two point in the intersect list, 
    // meaning  4 elements, latitude1,longitude1,latitude2,longitude2

    if (intersect.Count() >= 4)
    {
        if (distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao[3 * j + 2]     
            < distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao[3 * j + 5])
            {
             //....?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach to this problem, but if someone knows a better way to do this, please help. Thank you

Comment: It might make it easier if instead of having a list of `double` values, you had a list of a class that contained the lat, long and distance values?

Comment: Your for loop need to increment by two instead of one.  So change from : i++ to : i += 2

Comment: I could do that, but it would make more sence for me if it wasn't in a class

Comment: Why does `GetDistance` take `intLat` and `intLong` as strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
            List<double> distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao = new List<double>();

            
            for (int i = 0; i <= intersect.Count(); i++)
            {
                
                double intLat = intersect[2 * i];
                double intLong = intersect[2 * i + 1];
                
                var distancia = GetDistance(ocorrencia.Latitude, ocorrencia.Longitude, intLat.ToString(), intLong.ToString());

                
                distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.Add(intLat);
                distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.Add(intLong);
                distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.Add(distancia);

                
            }

            double minimum = 0;
            int index = 0;
            int j = 2;

                for ( j = 2; j <= distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.Count()-3; j+=3) 
                {
                    
                    if (intersect.Count() >= 4)
                    {
                        if (j == 2)
                        {
                            if (distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao[j] < distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao[j + 3])
                            {
                                minimum = distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao[j];
                                index = j;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                minimum = distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao[j + 3];
                                index = j + 3;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (minimum > distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao[j + 3])
                            {
                                minimum = distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao[j + 3];
                                index = j + 3;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a class, you can use a `ValueTuple` and LINQ to make this simple:

```
var distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao = new List<(double lat, double lon, double dist)>();

if (intersect.Count() > 2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < intersect.Count(); i += 2) {
        //get latitude
        double intLat = intersect[i];
        //get longitude
        double intLong = intersect[i + 1];
        //calculates the distance between the fixed point and the point of the list intersect
        var distancia = GetDistance(FixedLatitude, FixedLongitude, intLat.ToString(), intLong.ToString());

        //Add the latitude and longitude and long as the distance calculated to another list
        distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.Add((intLat, intLong, distancia));
    }
    
    var (closestLat, closestLon, closestDist) = distanciasOcorrenciaIntersecao.OrderBy(doi => doi.dist).First();
}
```